# Accessible introduction to L-shaped methods/Benders decomposition

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-programming, benders-decomposition

I am looking for papers or other resources that provide an accessible introduction to L-shaped methods/Benders decomposition for solving stochastic linear programming-ideally something focused more on the practical and implementation side. Birge and Louveaux's book on stochastic programming provides some good examples, but I find their explanations long-winded. What are some of the best resources for learning Benders decomposition?

Comment: I include references to L-shaped Benders decomposition in a question for decomposition, https://or.stackexchange.com/a/5772/3163

Answer (score 3):

Given your emphasis on practical and implementation aspects, I think the following two lectures will interest you:

1. [Stochastic Programming Modeling by Jeff Linderoth (University of Wisconsin, Madison)](https://www.ima.umn.edu/2015-2016/ND8.1-12.16/25379)
2. [Benders Decomposition for Solving Two-stage Stochastic Optimization Models by Jim Luedtke (University of Wisconsin, Madison)](https://www.ima.umn.edu/2015-2016/ND8.1-12.16/25378)

Comment: These two lectures look good, Thank you. I probably need more material, so will wait for others to add to the list