# Good book to get familiar with the key concepts of Operations Research for a person which didn't enjoy a good math education in university?

Tags: optimization, modeling, vehicle-routing, books, genetic-algorithm

I am currently reading research papers on optimization problems in logistics and struggle to understand the math notation. Any good beginner friendly books you would recommend?
This is the paper I read:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1366554514002269?casa_token=7OHpodgcRnUAAAAA:_VB4tS4ZjTx5TC5HUr7QbiAhxZX07WCxC15cLTnF1nXI-QQ2sKgmoyvJrBxq_YDqtFlBAyWY2g#b0100

Comment: I recommended seeing [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-are-good-reference-books-for-introduction-to-operations-research), [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/117/recommended-books-materials-for-practical-applications-of-operations-research-in), and [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5770/textbook-recommendation-for-linear-programming-decomposition-fundamentals), links. Also, there are lots of resources that can be found in the community. :)

Comment: @A.Omidi Thank you!